# Catch 404 error with XHR

Tags: javascript, http

I have created a small javascript library for a project and in this library I have a function that detect when we are on a 404 page or not.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 404) {
                console.log("404 detected");
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open('HEAD', window.location.href);
    xhr.send();
```

It works for the majority of cases. But I have an issue on something.

When I reach a page with a POST query, this function tells me that it's a 404 page. I think it's because the xhr request try to call the page with a classic GET query (in order to not re-submit the form) and then the webapp return a 404 because the page does not accept GET query.

I'm trying to find a way to detect when I'm in this case and then, don't fire a "404 detected". I don't know if this is even possible with javascript.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are currently sending it with a `HEAD` method. Maybe that server only accept `POST` on that route and return a 404 to everthing else. Try to send it with `POST`

Comment: @litelite : the problem is that I can detect on which protocol the page has been called in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think it's because the xhr request try to call the page with a classic GET query

Sort of. See [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2):

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
> send a message body in the response (i.e., the response terminates at
> the end of the header section).

---

> I'm trying to find a way to detect when I'm in this case and then, don't fire a "404 detected". I don't know if this is even possible with javascript.

JavaScript is largely irrelevent. It comes down to HTTP. The answer is the same for whatever programming language you use to make the HTTP request.

You make a request and see what the response is. There is a specific request type for getting the headers from a GET request without the body (HEAD, which you are using). It isn't 100% reliable as some servers don't implement it correctly.

There isn't anything like that for POST in the standard.

The only 100% reliable way to find out if a given request is going to get a 404 response or not is to actually make that request.

Comment: JS is my only way of retrieve info on the page / request. So maybe the answer to my original question is "no, it's not possible"